# Xcode 8.0 Storyboard scrollview's content view autoresizing issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, storyboard, autoresize

Facing an issue with Xcode 8. While i open my existing old project with storyboards, most of the UIViews and all the UIScrollView subviews are miss aligning and subview's height and width becomes double (like width:320 becomes 640). It looks like there is a layout bug in Xcode 8. Mostly the issues are with UIScrollView subviews layout. On redesigning layout, saved and closed the Xcode. If i open the same project with Xcode 8 again, this time again layout frame is changing for scrollviews and few UITabeViewCell contents centring to one location. Too much time is wasting because of this bug in Xcode 8.

In this image display scrollview>SingleView>ImageView with proper alignment.

1.[Click for see image when i open storyboard first time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCtP4.png)

but when i reopen storyboard, it change with alignment of SingleView size and ImageView size.

2.[Click for see image when i open storyboard second time.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8cVG.png)

is there any solution ?

Comment: Update your Xcode is the simple solution .

Comment: this was known bug in xcode 8.0 update your xcode.

Comment: only solution is update your xcode,

Comment: is there any solution without update xcode ?

Comment: if in your old project all constrain are perfect then you have to just select view as iPhone SE

Comment: In Xcode 7 perfect work all view but in Xcode 8 change scrollview's content view size and alignment. and it's every time change.